# MockBean in SpringBootTest depends on executing order despite DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

Given the following class definition:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)
public class ErrorHandlerTest{
    @MockBean
    private ErrorHandler errorHandler;
```

the successful injection of the `@MockBean` annotated class `ErrorHandler` depends on the execution order of all tests. As the class has DirtiesContext set to `BEFORE_CLASS`, I would not expect side effects from other classes.

- If this Test is executed first, the mocked Bean is injected and the test succeeds.
- If any other Test is executed before this test, the mocked Bean is not injected, but the context is reused. Resulting in a failure of the test.

At first I thought that the DirtiesContext may override the mocked Bean, but as the test executes successfully standalone (or in the right order), and there isn't any indication of an actual new context. I have disregarded that thought.

If the class preceding the test is annotated with  `DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS` the mocked Bean is injected.

Why does using `AFTER_CLASS` in the class before work, but `BEFORE_CLASS`in the current class not?

Comment: How about `@DirtiesContext` on method level?

Answer (score 0):

When you say @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS) in your current test class, it's like saying, "Hey, let's mess things up before any test starts!" This means everything gets reset before the first test begins, even if some cool stuff was set up before, like your @MockBean thing.

Now, if you go for @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS) in the class just before yours, it's like saying, "Hold on, let's tidy up after all the tests in that class finish." This makes sure everything is clean before your test starts, so it doesn't get confused by what happened in the previous class.

In simple words, choosing between BEFORE_CLASS and AFTER_CLASS depends on when you want this cleaning to happen. Using AFTER_CLASS in the class before yours is like making sure everything is neat and tidy before your test begins, so there's no unexpected mess. But if you use BEFORE_CLASS in your current class, things might get a bit tricky if the cleaning isn't done properly before your mocked bean becomes the star of the show.